# How do i get my header to say a Username if he's already logged in (PHP)

Tags: php, html, session

I've searched the net far and wide but cant find a solution. I've tried many different things but nothing works. My header just always displays Login instead of Welcome "User" and a logout button. This is the code I have, and in my mind there should be no reason why it doesnt work but I'm sure ive made a little syntax error or maybe i'm just really far off

```
<?php

require_once('WebsiteUser.php');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(false);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<header class="clearfix">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/blaktop.jpg" alt="blaktop logo" title="blaktop"/></a>
            <div id="signin">
                <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['WebsiteUser']))
{
      echo("Welcome " . $_SESSION['username']);// displays username
  echo("<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> ");
}
else
{
  echo("<a href='userlogin.php'>Login</a> ");
}
?>
            </div>
        </header>
 </html>
```

WebsiteUser.php is my connect type file this is the source code for it

```
<?php

class WebsiteUser{
/* Host address for the database */
protected static $DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
/* Database username */
protected static $DB_USERNAME = "admin";
/* Database password */
protected static $DB_PASSWORD = "password";
/* Name of database */ 
protected static $DB_DATABASE = "btc";

private $username;
private $password;
private $name;
private $mysqli;
private $dbError;
private $authenticated = false;

function __construct() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(self::$DB_HOST, self::$DB_USERNAME, 
            self::$DB_PASSWORD, self::$DB_DATABASE);
    if($this->mysqli->errno){
        $this->dbError = true;
    }else{
        $this->dbError = false;
    }
}
public function authenticate($username, $password){
    $loginQuery = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = ? AND passwrd = ? ";
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($loginQuery);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->authenticated = true;
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
}
public function isAuthenticated(){
    return $this->authenticated;
}
public function hasDbError(){
    return $this->dbError;
}
public function getUsername(){
    return $this->username;
}
}
?>
```

And heres the code for when somebody logs in

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        if($_POST['username'] == "" || $_POST['password'] == ""){
            $missingFields = true;
        } else {
            //All fields set, fields have a value
            $websiteUser = new WebsiteUser();
            if(!$websiteUser->hasDbError()){
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $websiteUser->authenticate($username, $password);
                if($websiteUser->isAuthenticated()){
                    $_SESSION['websiteUser'] = $websiteUser;
                    header('Location:index.php');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be you're not handling logins properly. We can't tell from this. Please show us the testcase (http://sscce.org) you've been debugging with.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit added some more of my code, hopefully that helps

Comment: No I asked for your testcase and provided a link that you should follow to find out what that is.

Answer (score -2):

```
<? 
$user = $_GET['user']; 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['user'] = $user; 

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ 
} else { 
echo " 
<script language='javascript'> 
alert('Sorry, but you must login to view the members area!') 
</script> 
<script> 
window.location='http://example.com/login.html' 
</script> 
"; } 
?>




<? echo "Welcome, $user"; ?>
```